# How to update state that is passed through react router link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, state, routerlink

So I am using react-router, and after I send some state with the Link from page1 to page2

```js
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: `/dashboard/edit/${resort.id}`,
    state: { resort: resort },
  }}
  style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: 'black' }}
>
  <i
    className="fas fa-edit db-icon"
    style={{ background: 'rgb(12, 177, 12)', color: 'black' }}
  ></i>
</Link>;
```

When I enter page2, how do I update this state, I've tried using `this.setState`, but that doesn't work, I've tried destructuring the state sent over like below but that didn't work either

```js
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    title,
    price,
    desc,
    img,
    smoking,
    guests,
    featured,
  } = this.props.location.state.resort;        
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you log `this.props.location.state` to ensure you're getting the state? You should definitely be using `setState`.

Comment: Yes Im receiving the state, I just dont know how to update it @Ace

Comment: Can you show how you are using `setState`?

Comment: this.setState({featured: !this.props.location.state.resort.featured}) @Ace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> NEVER mutate `this.state` directly

Try like this:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = { resort: {} };      
}

componentDidMount = () => {
  this.setState({resort: this.props.location.state.resort});
}
```

Comment: Isn't it bad practice to call set state in componentdidmount?

Comment: Great answer! Didn't seen this before I posted mine.

Comment: @fortunee I was only a few seconds early I guess :v

Comment: @AbdurahmanHijazi No, according to the React Documentation it's perfectly OK to call `setState()` from within the `componentDidMount()`

Comment: Makes sense thank you both @fortunee and Xenon

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook and use `setState` to set those values to the component `state` like this

Like this

```js
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    resort: {}
  }
}

compoonentDidMount() {
  this.setState({ resort: this.props.location.state.resort })
}
```